# How do I use If statements in the Table.ReplaceValue to find blank or empty cells

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I'm using Power Query in excel and I'm trying to use the ReplaceValues Function with IF statements on a string column and for some reason it's not working with the blank cells.  Below is my code.

```
=Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step", 
each [Column1],
each if [Column1] = "" or [Column1] = null then "n/a"
else if [Column1] = "Strings" or [Column1] = "Strings2" then "Yes"
else [Column1],
Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"})
```

I also tried this with no success:

```
=Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous Step", 
each [Column1],
each if Text.Trim([Column1]) = "" or [Column1] = null then "n/a"
else if [Column1] = "Strings" or [Column1] = "Strings2" then "Yes"
else [Column1],
Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"})
```

I even tried putting a space between the `""` and that didn't work either.  Are there any other solutions that I can use as a workaround so that my If Statement can pick up blank or empty cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is not text, so `Replacer.ReplaceText` will not work. Use `Replacer.ReplaceValue` instead.

I've just made that one change to your first code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method of coding the `Table.ReplaceValue` function.

```
   #"Replace"=Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Previous Step",
        each [Column1],
        "n/a",
        (x,y,z)=> if (x??"")="" then z 
            else if x="Strings" or x = "Strings2" then "Yes" 
            else x,
        {"Column1"})
```

See Example 4 under Microsoft [Help for this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-replacevalue) for an explanation of the variables passed `(x,y,z)`

Note the use of the coalescing operator to handle the `null or blank` detection.

And another way of using the same method but with perhaps more understandable variables:

```
#"Replace"=Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Previous Step",
        each ([Column1]??"") = "",
        "n/a",
        (existing,isBlank,replace)=> if isBlank then replace 
            else if existing="Strings" or existing="Strings2"
                then "Yes" else existing,
        {"Column1"})
```

Answer (score -1):

see if it helps

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step", {{"Column1", each if _ = null or _ = "" then "n/a" else if _ = "Strings" or _ = "Strings2" then "Yes" else _, type text}})
```